# How to return device local admin password using Microsoft graph Api using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-app-registration

Am having a problem exporting local admin password for devices configured with LAPS using Microsoft graph api. The conventional `get-lapsadpassword` cmdlet works fine but graph api
doesn't. I suspect the problem is in the query endpoint because when i run `$credentialsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceLocalCredentials"` it retrieves well but the problem with `list device credentials` does not return the credential as per Microsoft documentation.

I have this permission assigned to my app registration `DeviceLocalCredential.ReadBasic.All, DeviceLocalCredential.Read.All`

This is my code

```
   $accessToken = "token here"
   $deviceId = "defe99b4-72f6-44c4-82ae-8dd4ff700b46"
   
    #request to the deviceLocalCredentials endpoint for the selected device
    $credentialsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceLocalCredentials/$deviceId?$select=credentials" -Headers @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
        "ContentType" = "application/json"
        "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
      
}
    # credentials response
    $credentialsResponse
    $credentials = $credentialsResponse.value
    $credentials
```

when i run that code i get the error below and a partial response. What could be wrong?
[image]

I expect atleast to see the entire json response as per Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/devicelocalcredentialinfo-get?view=graph-rest-beta)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceLocalCredentials/b465e4e8-e4e8-b465-e8e4-65b4e8e465b4?$select=credentials
User-Agent: "Dsreg/10.0 (Windows 10.0.19043.1466)"
ocp-client-name: "My Friendly Client"
ocp-client-version: "1.2"
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
  "value": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.deviceLocalCredentialInfo",
    "id": "b465e4e8-e4e8-b465-e8e4-65b4e8e465b4",
    "deviceName": "LAPS_TEST",
    "lastBackupDateTime": "2023-04-21T13:45:30.0000000Z",
    "refreshDateTime": "2020-05-20T13:45:30.0000000Z",
    "credentials": [
      {
        "accountName": "ContosoLocalAdminAccount",
        "accountSid": "S-1-5-21-2318549658-1590267884-3984890135-1965",
        "backupDateTime": "2023-04-21T13:45:30.0000000Z",
        "passwordBase64": "UQBRAEAAZAA4AGYAOABnAFkA"
      },
      {
        "accountName": "ContosoLocalAdminAccount",
        "accountSid": "S-1-5-21-2318549658-1590267884-3984890135-1965",
        "backupDateTime": "2023-03-22T13:45:30.0000000Z",
        "passwordBase64": "KgBEADkAawBsAGsAZgAjADQA"
      },
      {
        "accountName": "Administrator",
        "accountSid": "S-1-5-21-2318549658-1590267884-3984890135-500",
        "backupDateTime": "2023-02-23T13:45:30.0000000Z",
        "passwordBase64": "TABwAGQAOQAqACgAKQAzADQA"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The $select in your url gets expanded as a variable because you are using double quotes (so $select will be replaced with the value of a variable $select OR with an empty value of this is null).

Comment: how should i write the query?